# Open Import Text Wizard in Access 2013 through VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to open the Import Text Wizard as part of my code after it's ftp'd down a text file.

I don't have the metadata of the file as each file could be different, the only things they have in common is that they are pipe delimited with no text qualifier with a header row. No consistency in column type or number of columns.

Hence I don't think I can easily use `docmd.transfertext` as the specification would have to be different each time.

I don't mind pushing people down the manual route but if I look this up the instructions are to use `Docmd.RunCommand acCmdImport`. This appears to then be deprecated after Access 2007 as if I run it I get Run-time error 2002 saying the function or feature isn't installed in this version.

What I'm after is either:

- A way to open the wizard

or

- A way to import / link the text files without knowing the metadata ahead of the import.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is:

```
Docmd.RunCommand(acCmdImportAttachText)
```

That opens the wizard as if you called it from the band.